# Как корректно установить иконки для JMenuItem в своем классе JMenu?

Tags: java, swing

Есть двумерный массив `ImageIcon`, содержащий иконки для подпунктов меню.

```
 private static final ImageIcon [][] icons = {
        {
                //ImageIcon newFileIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\New.PNG"),

                // ImageIcon openIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Open.PNG"),

                //ImageIcon saveIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Save.PNG"),

                //ImageIcon saveAsIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\SaveAs.PNG"),

                //ImageIcon printIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Print.PNG"),

                //ImageIcon exitIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Redo.PNG")

        },
        {
                // ImageIcon cutIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Cut.PNG"),
                // ImageIcon pasteIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Paste.PNG"),
                //ImageIcon copyIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Copy.PNG"),
                //ImageIcon undoIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Undo.PNG"),
                //ImageIcon redoIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Exit.PNG"),

                //ImageIcon redoIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Redo.PNG"),

                //ImageIcon selectAllIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\SelectAll.PNG"),
                //ImageIcon deleteIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Delete.PNG")
        },
        {

                //ImageIcon fontIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Font.PNG"),
                //ImageIcon alignmentIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Alignment.PNG"),
                // ImageIcon colorIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Color.PNG")

        },
        {//ImageIcon helpIcon =
                new ImageIcon("D:\\TextEditor\\src\\TextEditor\\images\\Help.PNG")}
};
```

Есть мой класс, в котором я создаю меню.

```
public class TextEditorMenuItem extends JMenu {


private JMenuItem mi;
private String menuName;
private JMenu menuItem;
private ArrayList<ImageIcon> itemIcons = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();


TextEditorMenuItem(String menuName, ImageIcon [][] icons, String... menuItemNames) {
    this.menuItem = new JMenu(menuName);

    for (String mis : menuItemNames) {
        mi = new JMenuItem(mis);
        menuItem.add(mi);
        }
    }


        for(ImageIcon[] array : icons){
        for (ImageIcon i :array){
            mi.setIcon(i);
        }
    }



public JMenu getItems () {
    return menuItem;
};

};
```

У меня не получается корректно установить иконки. Делаю это так: (в комментариях указана идея  того, как это должно работать)

```
    // пробегаем по каждому одномерному массиву в массиве icons  
   for(ImageIcon[] array : icons){
        // для каждого JMenuItem устанавливаем иконку с индексом этого элемента (если находимся на первой итерации внешнего цикла, устанавливаются иконки icons[0][i])
        for (ImageIcon i :array){
            mi.setIcon(i);
        }
        // переходим к иконкам icons[1][i]
    }
```

и каждому пункту меню устанавливается последний элемент массива `icons`. Подскажите, где я ошибся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К каждой иконке в массиве `icons` я добавил `Description`, а каждому `JMenuItem` имя, а затем выполнил в цикле проверку, совпадают ли описание иконки и имя пункта меню. Если совпадают устанавливаем эту иконку.

```
       for (String mis : menuItemNames) {
        mi = new JMenuItem(mis);
        mi.setName(mis);
        for(ImageIcon[] array : icons){
            for (ImageIcon i : array){
                if(i.toString() == mi.getName()){
                mi.setIcon(i);
                }

            }

        }
        menuItem.add(mi);
        }
```